# Literature leading up to algebraic topology

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, reference-request

First and foremost, allow me to apologise for the quite general and perhaps vague nature of this question and for the presence of any misunderstandings in the statements I will use.

I know very well that in order to tackle more difficult questions and concepts, one must first plow away at mastering the basic constructs.
But as is often the case, one learns about these very late if one's academic focus hasn't been mathematics. Hence, as a disclaimer, I am self-studying maths to do some better science, but due to time-constraints I've taken more of a breadth-first search approach, which hasn't been very fruitful as it has only left me with dodgy notions.

I've tried my hand at topology, but I couldn't grasp its abstract, rather non-constructive roots. I'm more attracted to the algebraic perspective, but its advanced applications seem still far away and I have no intuition for combinatorics to speed up things.
I would like to combine a bit from all of the above in order to actually do some rigorous calculations.

*I shall give an example of my (perhaps misguided) perspective. Feel free to point out misconceptions/mistakes (as they could tell me what to focus on):*

Heuristically, diagonalization-type arguments fail on countable bases due to the correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$ and its implicit restrictions: inequalities between numbers and the powers in their prime factorization (equivalently, $\mathbb{Q}$ and a finite fraction expansion - e.g. $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0;1)$ has 0 as a fixed point under repeated iterations of $f : [0,1) \to [0,1) ,\quad f(x) = 1/x - \lfloor1/x\rfloor \equiv 1/x \; \mathrm{mod} 1$, where $f$ might be recognized from the familiar recurrence relationship in continued fraction approximation $\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{\lfloor f^{\circ n}_{(x)}\rfloor \cdot p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}}{\lfloor f^{\circ n}_{(x)}\rfloor \cdot q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}}$  with suitable boundary conditions for $n = 0$ as $f^{\circ 0} \equiv x \mapsto x$).
This should lead to algebraic arguments, with suitably chosen restrictions on the ideals of some ring (which I do not know how to do at all). One is left wondering if all the possible closed operations need to be compatible with  sequences in prime factorization.

Moving to uncountable bases, a lot more seems possible, but I always get the impression that one could do away with these if there is a suitable projection to a compact set that respects the topology. I assume this gives rise to special measures.

**If the above makes some sense, I guess the main question is:**

I would like to be able to enumerate equivalence classes more properly. I know there should be a systematic way to derive sequences based on some topological information (and vice-versa) and this leads to some proper algebraic topology.
But what would I need to focus on to climb that mountain? I mean, what would it be necessary for someone who starts at the level of rigor of math courses in the sciences (at graduate-level) to end up understanding and applying algebraic topology?

Comment: What do you mean by "the level of rigor of math courses in the sciences"?

Comment: That is a good question indeed. It mostly depends on what is taught at each university. I suppose it means the level where any non-commutative operation is closed as part of a group and we may freely side-step convergence issues (which this question is mostly all about, since, to the best of my knowledge, conditionally convergent sequences should define a specific ordering compatible with sequence(s) of set inclusion defining a given topology)